# Javascript foreach loop and state

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am making a Book List where users can enter the name of a book and can click the read button if the user has read the book.This is done by toggling a class.

However, after adding a new book to the list one of the other books lists can't   have there class toggled.

```
       var readBtn=document.getElementsByClassName(DOMstrings.readButton);

       Array.from(readBtn).forEach(function(curr){

            curr.addEventListener('click',function(){
                curr.classList.toggle('read');

            });

        })
```

user should be able to toggle the class of any book added to the list not just the lastest book added

Comment: please provide a [mcve] that shows the problems you are having

Comment: Well do you find the click handler to the new elements you create? That code does not just run every time you add elements....

Comment: When do you call the code that adds the listeners? If you were to call this code everytime you add a new `readButton`, the event listeners would 'stack' on the ones that were there before and toggle twice, so basically not at all.

Comment: @KonstantinDobler I call the listener each time the user adds a new book to the list

Comment: I have finally managed to solve my problem instead of looping from the nodelist instead used event delagation